# revit C# filtering floors based on structural material

Tags: c#, revit-api

Is there any way we can differenitate between architectural and structural floors in C# revit api? I am trying to filter floors of a certain level using the StructuralMaterialTypeFilter but the result I am getting is empty list. But there are 8 floors on the input level. my code is

```
StructuralMaterialTypeFilter concreteMaterial = new StructuralMaterialTypeFilter(StructuralMaterialType.Concrete,true);
        FilteredElementCollector col = new FilteredElementCollector(document).WherePasses(concreteMaterial).OfClass(typeof(Floor));
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the BuiltInParameter FLOOR_PARAM_IS_STRUCTURAL and check this parameter for the floors in your collection.

Best regards,
François